# PHP Includes Does Not Work

Tags: php, include

There is a web application I just signed on to develop. After pulling the code from Github, I have been trying to get it working on my local development set up. There is one problem. The file called "signup_action.php" starts off like this:

```
 <?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

echo getcwd() . "<br>"; //for testing
echo getcwd() . "/code/includes.php" . "<br>"; //for testing

include("./code/includes.php");
//include(getcwd() . "/code/includes.php");

echo("Hello from point 3 <br>"); //for testing
...
```

Then, if I go to the beginning of the code/includes.php, I have the following:

```
<?php

echo "Hello from point 1 of code/includes.php" . "<br>";

include_once("local_config.php");
//ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");

date_default_timezone_set("EST");
```

The output of the signup_action.php in the browser is:

> /Users/genericuser/www/sites/project1
>
> /Users/genericuser/www/sites/project1/code/includes.php

Why am I not seeing any "echo" output from includes.php? I started troubleshooting this after I discovered that the signup_action.php was not performing its function and was giving me a blank page. Is the include() working?

Comment: `var_dump(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()));` should tell you how PHP prefixes the path you're passing to `include`. Then you might see that the dot in `./code/includes.php` doesn't really make sense. Use an absolute path, use a relative path + magic constants like `__DIR__` (the dir of the current file), or set your include path correctly. PS I hate titles like _"X isn't working"_ whereas the real problem is _"I'm not using X correctly"_

Comment: I have tried all of the above. It is just some of them produce the same result as the others, i.e., the blank page I mention above.

Comment: you can replace `include()` calls by `require()` and similarly `include_once()` by `require_once()` to assert your last assumption (you will get some error message if any of those fail with the require equivalents).

Comment: That was how I had it originally: includes("code/includes.php"). But this also does not produce any "echo" from includes.php

Comment: @ArtforLife: Show your include path, show your directory structure, check your logs and ini settings, check output buffers (if any), use a debugger, or -if you don't know how to use/install them- revert to the old-school `var_dump`, `die` and `__compiler_halt` calls

Answer (score -1):

include_once and date_default_timezone should be settled before others PHP code operation.

include_once("local_config.php");
//ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");

date_default_timezone_set("EST");

echo "Hello from point 1 of code/includes.php" . "
";